# .Net 5.0 not supported in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have publish aws serverless app to Amazon Lambda but it is showing me below error that it is not able to find .net 5.0 framework.
[image]
Does Amazon Lambda not support .NET 5.0 framework ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No Lambda does not have a native runtime for .NET 5. You can see the currently supported runtimes listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html). Right now only .NET Core versions 2.1 and 3.1 are supported natively.

You can use .NET 5 if you use containerized lambda functions. [See docs for info on that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-image.html).

Comment: You can also use .NET 5 as a custom runtime, as described in "exploring-net-5-with-the-aws-toolkit-for-visual-studio": https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/exploring-net-5-with-the-aws-toolkit-for-visual-studio/